# Python mapreduce sample codes

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a simple MR program to find number of lines containing word "Private" in a file. The map phase works well but reduce phase fails continuously. I am pasting the code here....
Mapper :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input) 
# the mapper will get number of records containing word "Private"
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    count = 0
    string = "Private"
    string = string.strip()
    count = count + 1
    # increase counters
    for word in words:
    if word == string:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be go through the shuffle proess and then 
        # be the input for the Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
                print '%s\t%s' % (string ,count)
```

Reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import itemgetter
import sys
current_sum = 0

# input comes from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    string, count = line.split('\t', 1)

        try:
        count = float(count)
    except ValueError:
             continue

        current_sum = current_sum + count
            print '%s\t%s' % (string, current_sum)
```

I am getting following messages while the jobs fail

15/09/04 10:45:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/09/04 10:45:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1441341950773_0003
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1441341950773_0003
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://meenal-Vostro-3546:8088/proxy/application_1441341950773_0003/
15/09/04 10:45:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1441341950773_0003
15/09/04 10:45:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1441341950773_0003 running in uber mode : false
15/09/04 10:45:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/09/04 10:45:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1441341950773_0003_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Comment: The errors look like a Hadoop system failure and not necessarily a problem with your reducer, however the indentation in the reducer starting with try is off and you should test both the mapper and reducer locally and separately first simply by using cat to feed data to the mapper's stdin and same for the reducer for which its data may need to be prepared.  Such testing is shown in http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/.  When the mapper and reducer has been fully debugged and tested, try using them in another map-recuce job.

Comment: Thanks. I had changed the indentation and tried ... it worked... thanks

Comment: Error code 1 usually means a mapper/reducer mistake. Testing your mapper and reducer in unix would help to troubleshoot (`cat input_files | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py`). In addition, you could find a clue looking at the hadoop output logs - `yarn logs -applicationId application_1441341950773_0003` or directly on hdfs `hdfs dfs -ls /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/{user}/logs`.